# JWT authentication in Laravel without database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, jwt, guzzle

I have a question regarding Authentication in Laravel 5.x. I’ve been specifically looking at `tymondesigns/jwt-auth` and `irazasyed/jwt-auth-guard` packages to do the JSON web token authentication token handling in my Laravel application.

I am not using a local database whatsoever, nor do I want to. I have environment variables set up in .env for my API’s `URL, USERNAME & PASSWORD`. The Guzzle PHP HTTP client is doing the trick just fine, connecting and returning data between the API and my application as needed.

However, I need to set up Authentication within my Laravel instance. I run into problems here, and the auth is wanting a DB connection.

```php
$token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)
```

Here's the exception:

> ```
> PDOException in Connector.php line 55: 
> SQLSTATE[HY000] [14] unable to open database file
> ```

1. How can I make use of JWT without using a database?
2. How can I COMPLETELY shut-off database connections within Laravel?

Thanks.

---

**UPDATE:**

Using `tymon/jwt-auth,` I've set things up within the routes, Kernel, Middleware, etc.

I created a "claim" successfully, but I need to create the token by encoding the "payload."

```php
$this->username = $request->username;

$sub = $this->username;
$iat = time();
$jti = md5($sub . $iat);
$aud = env('APP_URL');

$this->claims = [
    'sub' => $sub,
    'iat' => $iat,
    'exp' => time() + (2 * 7 * 24 * 60 * 60),
    'nbf' => $iat,
    'iss' => 'khill',
    'jti' => $jti,
    'aud' => $aud,
];

$payload = JWTFactory::make($this->claims);
```

How do I get the custom token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a quick fix I decided to implement the following custom code...

**1) Created custom middleware to handle the logic.**

```
class CustomMiddleware
{
    protected $loginPath = 'login';

    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
        $logged_in = $request->session()->get('logged_in');

        if (!$logged_in) {
            return redirect()->guest('login')->with('flag','1');
        }

    return $next($request);
    }
}
```

**2) Added a reference to the middleware class.**

```
class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'custom' => \App\Http\Middleware\CustomMiddleware::class,
    ];
}
```

**3) Added it to routes.php.**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['custom']], function () {
    // Add routes here
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should define a custom *Authentication Provider* and set it in *config/jwt.php*.

---

#### Example of provider

Put this class anywhere you like.

```
namespace MyNamespace;

use Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\Auth\AuthInterface;

class MyCustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthInterface
{
    public function byCredentials(array $credentials = [])
    {
        return $credentials['username'] == env('USERNAME') && $credentials['password'] == env('PASSWORD');
    }

    public function byId($id)
    {
        // maybe throw an expection?
    }

    public function user()
    {
        // you will have to implement this maybe.
    }
}
```

---

#### Example of configuration

In the `providers` array in *config/jwt.php*, change this:

```
'auth' => 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\Auth\IlluminateAuthAdapter',
```

to this:

```
'auth' => 'MyNamespace\MyCustomAuthenticationProvider',
```

---

#### Other considerations

1. Using the `env()` function anywhere is not good practice. It's better to use it in your config files, and then use the `config()` function anywhere else.
2. You may need to reimplement also the *User Provider*.

Answer (score 1):

JWTAuth::attempt() won't help you with this, because it hits the database for you behind the scenes. You need some other way to check the environment credentials.

Add a custom method to a class somewhere which will do that for you or pass the credentials against the API you are hitting with Guzzle.

Code example:

```
public function authenticate($username, $password)
{
    if(!$username === env('USERNAME') or !$password === env('PASSWORD')) {
       // return a message that the user could not be authenticated or false.
    }


    // Generate the JWT token here and store it somewhere. 
}
```

Comment: And despite the horrible examples for creating a custom token by tymondesigns/jwt-auth. What do you suggest @Ruffles? I can create a custom claim easy enough but how do I create the PayLoad, and the actual JWT Token so I can start authenticating Users and not let them access certain pages, etc. I just need something very simple and for some reason it escapes me.

Comment: You should still generate a token with the facade, but it's useless for the authenticating part.

Comment: Thank you. Then how do you create the token and what do you do with token once generated to employ it's use?

Comment: Check the docs or any tutorial that uses a database but instead of getting and saving data to the database, use your env variables or your API with Guzzle.

Answer (score 1):

yes.
you can create jwt token without database using tymondesigns/jwt-auth package...

for that you have to use jwt::encode method...

let me explain ...

first you have to put your credential in .env file...
then i am recomending you to use custom claims ...

after that you can create jwt token using below code ...

```
$customClaims = ['foo' => 'bar', 'baz' => 'bob'];
$factory = JWTFactory::customClaims($customClaims);
$token = JWTAuth::encode($payload);
```

for further details you can refer below link

[wiki](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki)

Comment: any way we can do the same for token verify.